# Is there a rails helper to render a collection in groups of 4 elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's what I want to do: I have a collection of `items` that I want to render in groups of 4.

```
<ul class="items row-fluid">
    <% @items.each do |item| %>

        <li class="well span3">
            <div>
                <h4 class="ellipsis toggle-ellipsis">  <%= link_to item.name,"#" %>  </h4>
            </div>

        </li>    
    <%end%>

</ul>
```

What I want to do is: to render 4 items in a ul, and then render the next 4 in another ul. I know how to do this manually (Introduce a `</ul><ul class=items>` everytime a counter%4=0). I was just wondering if there is a helper for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, there is, and you're probably going to kick yourself - http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
@items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  puts "current_index: #{index}
end
```

Index var is the counter.
So when index %4....